# Neural net for predicting pseudo periodic signal

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, forecasting

I'm currently working on a neural net to predict a pseudo periodic signal like described in [[1]](https://dspace.vsb.cz/bitstream/handle/10084/84205/AEEE-2008-7-1-2-342-babusiak.pdf?sequence=1). I don't work on ECG signals, but they are a pretty good source for testing.

Because I'm rather new in this field, I started with something simpler - predicting a sine. So I've created a NN with 3 sigmoid neurons in layer one and one linear neuron in layer 2 - but the result isn't what I expected. I'm using online training and RPROP btw.

Now, my questions are:
1) Should I switch to batch training for this purpose? 
2) What NN size do I need to predict something like a simple sine?

PS: Predicting simple constant values is working fine, so I expect my code to be working.

best 
Julz

---

[1]: Babusiak, B., & Mohylova, J. (2011). The EEG signal prediction by using neural network. Advances in Electrical and Electronic Engineering, 7(1-2), 342-345.

Comment: You might want to try using more than three neurons in the hidden layer.

Comment: I think, I have a different problem - therefore I have edited my question a bit.

Comment: I've excluded my second problem into a separate question to make things clear